# How to plot a discrete signal in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot a function y[n] = x[n+2]. My problem is that it does not plot in right range or even does not draw the zero sample points.

[image]

[image]

```
n = 1:6;
x = 1:1:8;

f = figure;
subplot(1,2,1)      
stem(n, x(n));
axis([-3,8, 0, 7]);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('x[n]');
title('Subplot 1')

subplot(1,2,2)       
stem(n, x(n + 2));     
xlabel('n');
ylabel('y[n]');
title('Subplot 2')
```

How to change the variables n or x to get the right plot? 
In the end, it ought to look like this:

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with it? It looks exactly like the function y = x(n + 2)

Comment: @Suever I edited the question. x[n]  is bounded from 0 to 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the concept of indices with your dependent variable. You should construct a function `x` which transforms an input `n` using the relationship that you know

```
function y = x(n)
    % Set all outputs to 0
    y = zeros(size(n));

    % Replace the values that fall between 0 and 6 with their same value
    y(n >= 0 & n <= 6) = n(n >= 0 & n <= 6);
end
```

Then you should pass this function a range of `n` values to evaluate.

```
nvalues = -3:8;
yvalues = x(nvalues);

stem(nvalues, yvalues)
```

You can also apply a transformation to the `n` values

```
nvalues = -3:8;
yvalues = x(nvalues + 2);

stem(nvalues, yvalues)
```

Comment: I get this error: In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same. Error in x (line 6)
    y(n >= 0 & n <= 6) = n;

Comment: @j35t3r Updated